convert dataframe from florida EDT to the California timezone
A database in Florida stores data from California in Florida day light saving time. Now, I want to convert it to the California time.
Code:
import pandas as pd
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

# Sample DataFrame (ensure it is defined correctly in your script)
data = {
    'Datetime': pd.date_range(start='2023-11-04', periods=10, freq='H'),
    'Data': range(10)
}
invdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
invdf.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True)

# Time zone information
eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')

# Localize the datetime to Eastern time zone considering daylight saving time
invdf['Datetime'] = invdf.index
invdf['Datetime'] = invdf['Datetime'].dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern', ambiguous='infer')

# Convert to Los Angeles time (Pacific time)
invdf['Datetime'] = invdf['Datetime'].dt.tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles')

# Reset the index to updated datetime
invdf.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True, drop=True)

Response:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AmbiguousTimeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[208], line 2
      1 invdf['Datetime'] = invdf.index
----> 2 invdf['Datetime'] = invdf['Datetime'].dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern', ambiguous='infer')
      3 # Convert to Los Angeles time (Pacific time)
      4 invdf['Datetime'] = invdf['Datetime'].dt.tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles')

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py:112, in PandasDelegate._add_delegate_accessors.<locals>._create_delegator_method.<locals>.f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    111 def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 112     return self._delegate_method(name, *args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py:132, in Properties._delegate_method(self, name, *args, **kwargs)
    129 values = self._get_values()
    131 method = getattr(values, name)
--> 132 result = method(*args, **kwargs)
    134 if not is_list_like(result):
    135     return result

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py:293, in DatetimeIndex.tz_localize(self, tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
    286 @doc(DatetimeArray.tz_localize)
    287 def tz_localize(
    288     self,
   (...)
    291     nonexistent: TimeNonexistent = "raise",
    292 ) -> Self:
--> 293     arr = self._data.tz_localize(tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
    294     return type(self)._simple_new(arr, name=self.name)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/_mixins.py:81, in ravel_compat.<locals>.method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     78 @wraps(meth)
     79 def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
     80     if self.ndim == 1:
---> 81         return meth(self, *args, **kwargs)
     83     flags = self._ndarray.flags
     84     flat = self.ravel("K")

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py:1088, in DatetimeArray.tz_localize(self, tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
   1085     tz = timezones.maybe_get_tz(tz)
   1086     # Convert to UTC
-> 1088     new_dates = tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc(
   1089         self.asi8,
   1090         tz,
   1091         ambiguous=ambiguous,
   1092         nonexistent=nonexistent,
   1093         creso=self._creso,
   1094     )
   1095 new_dates_dt64 = new_dates.view(f"M8[{self.unit}]")
   1096 dtype = tz_to_dtype(tz, unit=self.unit)

File tzconversion.pyx:328, in pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc()

File tzconversion.pyx:656, in pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion._get_dst_hours()

AmbiguousTimeError: 2023-11-05 01:00:00


at a glance, error suggests that some of your dates are not localised (without time zone). Add a timezone when building your date_range: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

Could reproduce with start='2023-11-05' like the error message has.  Nov 5, 2023 1am is ambiguous because it could be EST or EDT due to "fall back" one hour at 2am.

@MarkTolonen thanks for pointing that out; I didn't check when the DST transition actually happened.

If you create an hour-frequency daterange, it will not show the repeated hour of the DST transition (in this case; the other is a non-existent datetime, which would be there!). ambigous="infer" cannot work because there is nothing to infer, no repeated datetime. So if this example code represents the actual data, that data would simply be wrong. A "sane" way to treat this could be to set ambiguous="NaT", giving not-a-time values in the output instead of an error.
